# how to add icon to context menu in c# windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, icons, contextmenu

I am having a tree view in which if i right click any node context menu is displayed,Now i want to add icons corresponding to items in the context menu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're talking about `ContextMenuStrip` control, you can do that either it in the designer, by clicking on the item and selecting **"Set image..."**, or programmatically by changing the `Image` property of the `ToolStripMenuItem`.