# Adding icons to my menulist

Tags: c#, windows, contextmenu, notifyicon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to add icon to context menu in c# windows form application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555691/how-to-add-icon-to-context-menu-in-c-sharp-windows-form-application)

i've got a context menu attached to a task tray application. The code is as follows.

```
private NotifyIcon  trayIcon;
private ContextMenu trayMenu;

    trayMenu = new ContextMenu();

    trayMenu.MenuItems.Add("Login", OnLogin);
    trayMenu.MenuItems.Add("LogOut", OnLogOut);
    trayIcon = new NotifyIcon();
```

The problem is that I can't really seem to find any properties to set an image/icon to each menuitem. Is this possible to do? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555691/how-to-add-icon-to-context-menu-in-c-sharp-windows-form-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can add images within `ContextMenuStrip` but it's not possible to do this with `ContextMenu`. Here's a simple example on how to do this

**Example**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image ContextMenuStripItemImages = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Resources\International\Picrofo_Logo.png"); //Set the image from the path provided
    NotifyIcon trayIcon;
    ContextMenuStrip trayMenu;
    trayMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();
    trayMenu.Items.Add("Login", ContextMenuStripItemImages).Click += new EventHandler(Login_Click); //Create a new item in the context menu strip and link its Click event with Login_Click
    trayMenu.Items.Add("LogOut", ContextMenuStripItemImages).Click += new EventHandler(LogOut_Click); //Create a new item in the context menu strip and link its Click event with LogOut_Click
    trayIcon = new NotifyIcon();
    trayIcon.ContextMenuStrip = trayMenu; //Set the ContextMenuStrip of trayIcon to trayMenu
}

private void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do something when Login is clicked
}

private void LogOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do something when LogOut is clicked
}
```

**Notice:** When you are ready to show your `NotifyIcon` to the user, you may use `NotifyIcon.Visible = true;`

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: @DerekBrown No problems at all, I'm glad I could help. Have a great day :)